# Export 13 million records from SQL Server DB1 to another SQL Server DB2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have been asked to dump about 13 million rows from a SQL Server 2008 R2 database to another SQL Server 2008 R2 database, but both are on different database servers, and they have no common login.

It seems writing a C# program that uses ADO.NET SqlBulkCopy class is the only option and even with this, the program needs to run repeatedly every 'x' minutes till all data is copied.

**Is there any other better way to do this huge data transfer?**

Comment: How about bulk export import?

Comment: You mean bcp utility in SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, I have used it for data exceeding 3 million records, so it should be worth a shot

Comment: Ok. I will try running it from SSMS. Thanks.

Comment: Is the target servers table empty? Your quickest method is probably BCP.EXE native format. Export to a native file, copy the file over and import it.

Comment: Yes, it is. The target server table contains no data initially.